# How to change values/items stored in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I have created a website where the user enters the movie that they have previously watched, this is stored in a database and then outputted, using local storage on a separate page under their history. This worked for the first user, however the output under history doesn't change according to the user, as the values in local storage doesn't change. 
Is there another method of storage I should use, or can this be fixed using local storage.

```js
<script> //retrieving database results from localstorage in html page
        var film2s = localStorage.getItem("historynames");
       var films = film2s.split(",");
        var filmi = localStorage.getItem("historyimages");
        var images = filmi.split(",");
</script>
```

```html
<?php // retrieving users history from database
 for ($x = 0; $x<=$length -1; $x++){
        $select = $history[$x];
        $sql2= "SELECT FilmTitle FROM Films WHERE FilmID=".$select;
        $sql3= "SELECT imgFilm FROM Films WHERE FilmID=".$select;
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)> 0){
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                $h_films[] = $row2;
            }
            while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
                $h_img[] = $row3;
            }
        }
    }
    $h_names = array();
    $h_images = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x<=$length -1; $x++){
        foreach($h_films[$x] as $data){
           // echo ($data['FilmTitle']);
            array_push($h_names,$data);
          // array_push($names,$value);            
        }
    }  
    for ($x = 0; $x<=$length -1; $x++){
        foreach($h_img[$x] as $imgdata){
           // echo ($data['FilmTitle']);
            array_push($h_images,$imgdata);      
        }
    }  
?>






<script> // storing databse results from localstorage
    var users = <?php echo json_encode(($h_names)) ;?>;
    document.cookie= "historynames="+ users;
    var users2 = <?php echo json_encode(($h_images)) ;?>;
    localStorage.setItem('historyimages', users2);
</script>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? "Just" overwrite the keys/values in localStorage to update them. You might want to re-read them after changing

Comment: What do you consider a “user” here to begin with? Multiple people using the same site in the same browser on the same device, successively? I am not even sure I get what kind of system you actually want to create here. Localstorage would indicate we are dealing with something limited to a specific client, a server-side database being in the mix indicates rather the opposite …

Comment: Watch out for [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/); somebody could set some dangerous SQL into their localStorage and damage your database (because, as far as I can tell, "history" comes from the client). Also you don't need 2 separate queries for `FilmTitle` and `imgFilm` as they're coming from the same table; you also don't need the loop. Try experimenting with a query like `select FilmTitle, imgFilm from Films where FilmID in(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it simple and more secure you can store the values ​​in the cookies in php and use them anywhere in your steps page